# RichTextBox last change check

Tags: c#, forms, richtextbox

How can i know the last change that the user did in the text in RichTextBox?
Is there a function? 
Or I need to build to it a function?

Answer (score 1):

Add an event to your textbox. Select your textbox, go to properties, in event tab you will see different events. Find TextChanged event. Add that event to your code.

This function will trigger everytime textbox is changed. You can write your logic in that function.

Answer (score 0):

It provides an `event` called `TextChanged`. You'll need to define an `EventHandler` and specify what is to happen, when the text changes.

For example:

```
private void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char c = rtb.Text.ElementAt(rtb.Text.Length);
    if(c == mystring.ElementAt(mystring.Length))
      //is equal
    mystring = rtb.Text; //save string for next comparison
}
```

and now you need to add the eventhandler to the event like

```
rtb.TextChanged += rtb_TextChanged;
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) for documentation.

Comment: I guess, the question is about tracking the changes.

Comment: Thx but I wanted to know the last char change.
For example if my text is: "Text" and than I click 8 so the Text will be "Text8" so the char is 8.

Comment: Well, then save the string that was provided the last time and compare against it when the event is fired.

Comment: @bash.d: It works only if the update is the last character in the textbox. If the update was in the middle of the content. This might not work.

Comment: This is what YOU need to figure out. I gave you a possibility to check on this and not provide you with a working solution, which is not possible out-of-the box.

Answer (score 0):

`UpdatedChar` would contain the newly added character to the textbox1

`OldValue` would always contain the Old Value in the textbox1

***From your example*** :  if my text is: "Text" and than I click 8 so the Text will be "Text8" so the char is 8.

`UpdatedChar`=8 and 
`OldValue` = Text

```
    public string OldValue = string.Empty;

    public char UpdateChar;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newText = sender as TextBox;

        foreach (var val in newText.Text)
        {
            if(!OldValue.ToCharArray().Contains(val))
                UpdateChar = val;
        }

        OldValue = newText.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Note that changes to text are not limited to adding a single character: User could delete a char, a range or the whole text, paste a chunk of text, etc. Also, If entering characters via IME (as done in East-Asian languages), you'll see several characters get typed at once.