# I need to detect text change within the selected tab. How could I do this?

Tags: c#, winforms

So basically I'm making my own unsaved changes system that uses a public variable but I some how need to detect the text that's changed within the selected tab and then set the variable to true.

If it's not making sense still here's a simplified version:

Detect change within selected tab's richtextbox

change the bool to true

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is here, if it is about detecting that the current state of a rich text box is different from what you saved before, why not simply compare to what you saved last?

Comment: Additionally, what if I change something, but then change it back, should that still count as "unsaved"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RichTextBox last change check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658483/richtextbox-last-change-check)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use TextChanged event. For all of your RichTextBoxes you need to add `richtextbox_TextChanged` event.

you can use list for tracking text change per component seperately. items within changes list are the ones which has text change.

```
IList<string> changes = new List<string>();


private void richtextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Change Detected
    var componentName = sender.GetType().Name;
    if (!changes.Contains(componentName))
        changes.Add(componentName);

}
```